# Whats wrong with my simple If Else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, if-statement

Im new to RoR/Ruby and i cant seem to get the simplest thing to work. (trust me, ive search google and reread docs, i dont know what wrong)

So in my main view, I added the following:

```
<%= if 1>2 %>
  <%=     print "helllloooo" %>
<%= else %>
  <%= print "nada" %>
<%= end %>
```

And nothing is outputted..

**UPDATE****

Ok heres my new CORRECTED code and its STILL NOT WORKING

```
<th>
  <% if 1 > 2 %>
    <%= print "helllloooo" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= print "nada" %>
  <% end %>  
</th>
```

Comment: Is indentation matter ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your statements are not intended to be displayed so instead of

```
<%= if 1>2 %>
```

write

```
<% if 1 > 2 %>
```

Same thing for `else` and `end`

---

EDIT

```
<% if 1 > 2 %>
<%= "helllloooo" %>  #option 1 to display dynamic data
<% else %>
nada                 #option 2 to display static data
<% end %>
```

Comment: no `puts` => something to display => `<%= `, But it's not that useful if you don't display dynamic data

Comment: I updated my question with new code.. any suggestions as to what may be wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use `print`, or even ERB for the text. Also, your `if`, `else`, and `end` statements should be `<%`, not `<%=`:

```
<% if 1 > 2 %>
helllloooo
<% else %>
nada
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<%=` already means "print to the HTML response" in ERB (Ruby's own templating language).

So `<%= print '...'` means "print the return type of print '...'" which is nothing.

The right code would look like:

```
<% if 1>2 %>
<%= "helllloooo" %>
<% else %>
<%= "nada" %>
<% end %>
```

In fact you can even omit the `<%=` because you're just printing strings (not arbitrary objects):

```
<% if 1>2 %>
helllloooo
<% else %>
nada
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `=` is the problem. Use `<%` instead. `<%=` is for printing something, while `<%` is for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

for dynamic content use: <%= %>